# Posted values not being entered into database with simple PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

**Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['post_comment_submit'])){

    //Get all values
    $uid = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $rid = $_POST['rid'];
    $cmt = $_POST['post_reply_content'];
    $date = date('c');

    //Check that comment is not empty
    if(empty($cmt)){
        header('location: ../post.php?id='.$pid.'&error=incomplete');
        exit;
    }

    //Connect to database
    include "../inc/connect.php";

    //Prepare statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `post_comments` (`user_id`,`post_id`,`reply_id`,`comment`,`date`) VALUES (:uid, :pid, :rid :cmt, :date)");

    //Bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":uid",    $uid);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pid",    $pid);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rid",    $rid);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cmt",    $cmt);
    $stmt->bindParam(":date",   $date);

    //Execute
    if($stmt->execute()){
        header('Location: ../post.php?id='.$pid);
    } else {
        print_r("Error");
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($stmt);
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Error
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO `post_comments` (`user_id`,`post_id`,`reply_id`,`comment`,`date`) VALUES (:uid, :pid, :rid :cmt, :date) ) 
Array ( [pid] => 8 [rid] => 1 [post_reply_content] => Test Comment Reply [post_comment_submit] => Add comment )
```

**Explanation**

This is the `PHP` page that processes the data from a form. The function is to process a reply to a comment on a page by entering the user's ID, the post's ID, the ID of the comment this is a reply to, the comment content and the date/time of the comment.

**Question**

As you can see, the `PHP` file is receiving all the relevant `$_POST` data, but for some reason the SQL `INSERT` command is not processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma between `:rid` and `:cmt`.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `post_comments` (`user_id`,`post_id`,`reply_id`,`comment`,`date`) VALUES (:uid, :pid, :rid, :cmt, :date)");
```

Comment: Thanks so much for finding that so quickly. I've been fiddling about with every feature on each page for the last hour and it's the simplest thing. As soon as I can I'll accept this answer.